# How to alter a backbone.js collection using equivalent of .slice(start, end)

Tags: backbone.js

My Backbone Collection receives 30 models on fetch().

I have tried

```
   newColl=origColl.first(2);
```

to return a new Collection.  When I try to pass to the View it won't work.

Is there anyway to do this using an underscore.js method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but the following snippet might be what you are looking for.

```
var model = origColl.at(2);
var models = [model];
var newColl = new YourCollection(models);
```

***newColl*** will now be a new collection containing the model at position 2 of your original collection. The example is a bit more verbose than I would write it, but it might make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work likely because `first(n)` returns an array while your view is expecting a collection. You need to wrap it like this:

```
var newColl = new Backbone.Collection(origColl.first(2));
```

For a general "slice" you can use `find` in conjunction with `_.range`:

```
var newColl = new Backbone.Collection(origColl.find(_.range(start, end));
```

Naturally, tou can use your own collection class instead of `Backbone.Collection`.

See the documentation of `range` at http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#range.